# Keep a timer (coded in JS) that will automatically change color of image after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I started learning JS , saw below given example(in link) , thought of coding for automatic bulb switch on /off by modifying the existing example code.

Thought process is :
After user hits the image of bulb 1st time , bulb will automatically switch on / off.
Interval between switch on /off : 3 seconds.
For one hit the whole process continues for 2 mins or less.

Code example :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

existing code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
 <body>

 <h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>

 <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100"      height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>

 <script>
 function changeImage() {
   var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
     image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
   } else {
     image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
   }
  }
   </script>

    </body>
   </html>
```

code modification i did :

```
<script>
function changeImage() {

var t ;
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

while t < 90
{    
 t++ ;
setTimeout() : var delay= 3000 ;
if (image.src.match("bulbon")) 
   image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
else 
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
 }
                       }
 </script>
```

AND the above modified code does nothing.
Working code Change will be helpful for me understand more about JS.
Thank you

Comment: `setTimeout() : var delay = 3000 ;` This is not valid javascript, what is this? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
setInterval(function(){
if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
   image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
}else {
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
 };
},100);
```

This code will make the bubl change ever 0.1s

Answer (score 0):

if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
            setTimeout(function(){image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif"}, 3000);

```
            } else {
        setTimeout(function(){image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif"}, 3000);

            }
```

codepen url-  http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pbgGBg